# How to set or get Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor with reflection

Tags: vb.net, reflection

How can I use Reflection to set or retrieve the FlatAppearance.BorderColor property of a Button object?
Experiments with VB code ...

'MyObject refers to an existing Button object

Dim MyType As Type = MyObject.GetType

Dim MyPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo

PropertyInfo = MyType.GetProperty("FlatAppearance.BorderColor")

But above VB code fails and gives nothing back

Comment: `dim flatStyle = DirectCast([Some Button].GetType().GetProperty("FlatAppearance").GetValue([Some Button]), FlatButtonAppearance)` -- Is there a reason why, since you have the instance of a Control, you need reflection to read that value?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test ist. The reason using reflection ist, i'm building a inside script languagefor a spezial intercom application and the user can read and write  object properties from whithin the script language.

Comment: All right. Then you have to write something like: `dim flatProp = [Some Button].GetType().GetProperty("FlatAppearance").GetValue([Some Button])
flatProp.GetType().GetProperty("BorderColor").SetValue(flatProp, Color.Red)`

Comment: Hi, I have testet  your code snippet successfully. It woks fine for me. Thank you